# Adding a dataset to rdlc file

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Scenario:

I have an RDLC file - TestReport.rdlc
I have a form - Form1.cs
I have a ReportViewer - rptViewer

My datasource for the report will be an XML file or a datatable defined at run time (in button click event). Now when I am in design mode for the report how do I add the DataSource or DataSet to the report so I can "add" the columns/fields into the report?

Right now in the report when I click New -> DataSet I am asked to pick from Database, Service, Object or SharePoint but I want to use an object which exists in memory.

I am using VS2012.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

In case of XML, you have to create the schema for it and then add it to the report in the design view.

A little example is exaplained [in this blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/XmlReports04182007115639AM/XmlReports.aspx) (it's old but still good to understand what you have to do).

If also the XML's schema is dynamic, the only solution I came out is about to create one paramater for each node/attribute of your XML and build one or more .rdlc files for every type of XML